# SQL Server : where download examples of filled tables?

Tags: sql-server, datatables

I installed SQL Server Management Studio and SQL Server on my computer. Now I need filled tables for training. Where can I download completed (filled) tables (about 10k-100k rows) for my new db? For example - dictionaries, cataloges,...?

Thank you.

Comment: You can download the SO database. https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2015/10/how-to-download-the-stack-overflow-database-via-bittorrent/

Answer (score 0):

When installing SQL server it suggests to install sample database. I think it is called `AdventureWorks`. There are a lot of examples building on that DB.

Just follow [these steps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa992075.aspx).